# powerCLI restart VM guest from script

Tags: windows, powershell, vmware, powercli

i'm trying to run batch script which will call ps1 in order to restart VM guest. 
it's working when i ran it seperate but the problem is that powerCLI on CMD load without the arguments.

i have tried run it by steps :

```
echo on 
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noe -c ". \"C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\PowerCLI\Scripts\Initialize-PowerCLIEnvironment.ps1\" $true"
```

then on cmd :

```
connect -viserver -server "serverName" -Protocol https -User "user"-Password "pass"
```

then :

```
Restart-VM "VMserverName"  -RunAsync -Confirm:$false
```

it is all works fine separately but when try to combine it all - it is not working. 
seems like powerCLI load faster then the console write.

i have trying

```
Start-Sleep -s 10
```

command  but with no success.

how can i combine all 3 commands above in one file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute PowerShell commands from a cmd, you will have to pass them along using the Command-Switch of from PowerShell.

You could achieve what you want by executing the following command:

```
powershell -Command "Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core; Connect-VIServer -Server <server> -User <user> -Password <password>; Restart-VM <vm_name>  -RunAsync -Confirm:$false"
```

---

This is a very cumbersome way of doing this. I would suggest directly using PowerShell and have at least the ability to properly format the script:

```
Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Connect-VIServer -Server <server> -User <user> -Password <password>
Restart-VM <vm_name>  -RunAsync -Confirm:$false
```

You would still be able to call this PowerShell script from a cmd, by using the File-Parameter:

```
powershell -File <script>
```

Comment: works like a magic :-) i implement the second solution as you suggest.

Comment: Note that `Restart-VM` will trigger a hard reset of the VM, the equivalent of pressing the reset button on a physical machine. If you want to cleanly reboot the guest, use `Restart-VMGuest` instead.